# How do I prevent getting downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

TL;DR: I've gotten a previous account/IP address blocked from asking questions. It is pretty much the only thing I plan on using Stack Overflow for until I'm more experienced. I don't want to be a d*ck and consistently break any rules I might be breaking, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

---

I recently had my account blocked from using the site's most basic features, essentially removing its usefulness to me on that account. I don't want to continue breaking any rules that have gotten me banned, because I don't want to offend a community of (mostly) people who are here to help others.

Why have almost all the questions I've created received a negative voting score?

I'd also like to know if people are banned solely because of downvotes, and if not, what have I done to deserve a ban?

The posts aren't only on this account; they are also on [user1882226](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882226/user1882226) and [fazerXYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906642/fazerxyz).

To clarify, I have already read the FAQ and how-to-ask.html. I did this before asking any questions on my first account, and I am already complying with these.

Comment: Check the comments on your other question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160454/why-is-asking-specific-questions-about-a-narrow-situation-not-allowed

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160454/why-is-asking-specific-questions-about-a-narrow-situation-not-allowed#comment465127_160454

Comment: Spend some time reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) instead of wasting time on changing IPs and creating accounts

Comment: P.s. if [this is indeed also an account of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1882226/user1882226) you've not started using this site 3 days ago. And you've received several comments on your downvoted posts there as well. And instead of working around bans, I'm sure [you've read this by now as well of course](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)?

Comment: `Fortunately ip and account bans will not prevent me from using a website for more then about 3 minutes, as I can change my ip and create a new account.` The Moderators will *love* to hear that. Creating multiple accounts to circumvent a question ban will result in a permanent ban...the hard way.

Comment: @Bart, I have read most of it excluding some of the links, I disagree with certain things such as help vampirism which I would like to go into detail but it's far too philosophical and complicated as to why I disagree with it, but I will say this: I once couldn't use CreateWindowEx. After finding sample code and playing with it I now will probably never have problems with that or any other included functions. Some people learn more slowly then others, calling those that learn slowly "vampires" and shunning them is something I think is offensive.

Comment: oh and you're right, apparently it just seemed like about 3 days ago.

Comment: @user1931290 that particular question would have been answered by any textbook you could have picked up on the language. Even by any textbook on any somewhat similar language. And yes, we do expect you to do your homework. To teach yourself. We are not here for that. Or at least not at a level that basic.

Comment: By reading the comments i feel this site is like a School with some strict teachers and the users who asked questions should be have a fear to ask their questions like a School boy.

Comment: @user833985 That's not the case. We just ask that you put some effort into your own research before asking a question. Like reading a book on the programming language you're trying to learn for example. If you do that, and your question is clear, you will have no problem participating as a beginner. Just make sure you read the FAQ and you should be good to go. But given that this particular user kept asking bad questions, created multiple accounts and stated here and in another question that he would keep doing so, his reception was less than warm. Any regular user should be fine.

Comment: @Bart Please see the below link. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052010/javascript-keyword-color-in-visual-studio-2012) I Feel this question as silly which is not related to programming. Changing an option from the menu is not deserve any single down votes but one up votes. also it passes all rules like constructive,not localize and etc etc.

Comment: Also I can see something similiar to this thread already been asked.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276292/class-names-not-coloured-in-visual-studio-2012)how come these are related to programming. These questions should be asked to the technical people who installed the VS to the respective system or just google it.

Comment: @user833985 What's the problem with the first question you link? It's about software commonly used by programmers. It's not the most brilliant of questions, but it's fine. It's on-topic for the site as specified in the FAQ. That said, if you need clarifications of your own, by all means ask a question about it on Meta.

Comment: @user833985 If you think they are duplicates, flag one as such for moderator attention. We can't be expected to see everything. So if you do, great.

Answer (score 15):

You get downvoted because the questions you ask are not good in one way or another. It's really as simple as that. You have already received several comments on your questions, so you can't be completely oblivious to the fact that something is wrong. But let's go through some of them on your various accounts.

- There was this (now deleted) question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049927/

  In this question you were essentially asking us to provide you with a tutorial. That's not what we do here. Ask a question about a practical problem you face and we'll answer it. Question and answer. We don't link to tutorials. We don't recommend books. And we don't write entire tutorials. Don't ask us to tell you where you can find a solution. Ask us for help with the practical problem.
- Then there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894770/

  Essentially you're mucking around with code. Adding stuff that does really not belong there. A fun playground if you will. But with that, the awesomeness of the post does not go beyond the title. Something ended up beeping in the mess you created. While perhaps a fun exercise for someone to figure out, this is only ever relevant to you and the mess you created. As such it's too localized and closing it for that reason is fair.
- On another account we have https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14015451/1

  Without even looking at the content, look at the post. How does that look to you? Does it seem clear? Now try to read the text. It took me several times to even grasp what you were getting at, trying not to get lost in the mean time.

  For one very basic thing, format the code as code. Make it stand out. Split the text up in several easy to grasp paragraphs. Then we might still get lost in the question, but at least you've provided some clarity. And the comments on the particular question and the answer you received clearly indicate this. The users didn't get what you were asking.

That's 3 questions for you. Downvotes and close votes explained. Now read all of the content I've linked to before to see how you can improve. There are:

- [The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). Really, read it. Did that? Do so once again. Until you fully grasp it.
- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Essential. Especially the section on doing your homework.
- Jon Skeet's [excellent post on asking the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).
- And [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Though sometimes used in a snarky manner, the post is excellent.

Read all of them in full and make sure you understand. Not just that, make sure you understand where all your downvoted posts fail in some regard. Once you have a clear picture of that, improve your content where possible and see if you can get yourself unbanned.

But the major things are: Focus your questions. Keep them on-topic as specified by the FAQ. And please please please be clear.

As for the whole "I'll keep creating new accounts" deal.....yeah, don't do that. You'll run out of steam far before the moderators do. Just [read this instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Comment: Basically, SO is not really intended for people who have no clue what they're doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743150/how-to-read-the-return-value-from-a-function is the best example of that, it shows practically no understanding of how to program in C++ (or most other programming languages, since this is a common mechanism).

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. Users should by no means be afraid of asking a question, even if they are beginners. But don't expect the site to teach you how to program. You've got to learn this and we'll help you with your problems on the way. But a question like that would have been answered by any beginner text-book out there. Even the bad ones.

Comment: Thanks barmer and bart, I think the basic reason is due to "noobishness". Anyways I guess I'll just have to keep creating accounts and changing IP's anytime I get blocked from asking questions so that I can ask noobish questions again. I do my homework on the questions first, when about 15 minutes of google and half an hour of playing with the code doesn't help me I come here. Also, being banned isn't going to stop me since I basically look at it as adding 3 additional minutes to asking my question, since my question still gets answered (and yes those answers do help me.) It's too bad. thanks.

Comment: WTF? NO. Don't keep creating new accounts. Haven't you read my answer at all? Stop that. And no, 15 minutes of Google is not enough. Man, I'm sorry, but I did my best even after your previous question. If you receive a more permanent ban, it's all your own doing. <--- To anyone reading this, insert random expletives please.

Comment: I don't really understand why you think I can get a more permanent ban than ip/account ban, unless they plan on creating more steps to deter me from getting into this website like requiring rep just to ask questions or unless they make it so only whitelisted users who pass some sort of test can ask questions, I doubt they can do much more to prevent me from getting in here. Maybe I'm ignorant but so far I haven't encountered anything more "permanent" then IP/account bans... anywhere.

Comment: By all means feel free to try. I can't see you switching to any constructive behaviour soon, no matter how much effort I would put into helping you out. So yes, focus on creating new accounts and circumventing bans.

Comment: k, before you go I want you to know you have my sincere thanks either way though. goodbye.